# VBA ACCESS: Select/Filter exact + previous&next rows based on specific value

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to optimize the filtering of data in one report/table and I've encountered a challenge.
Table is located in m.access, so any vba access code or sql query should work here.

So far I've tried few options, but could not achieve expected results:

select prev_type, type, next_type
from (
select *,
lag(type) over (order by id) as prev_type,
type,
lead(type) over (order by id) as next_type
from table
) as t
where type = "type";

Basically I want to display from below table three rows:

1. row with Type = 'D'
2. previous row to the one with Type 'D'
3. next row to the one with Type 'D'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iilTn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a subquery:

```sql
Select * From YourTable 
Where Abs([ID] - (Select ID From YourTable Where [Type] = 'D')) <= 1
```

For multiple Ds, join the subquery:

```sql
Select 
    * 
From 
    YourTable ,
    (Select ID From YourTable Where [Type] = 'D') As T
Where 
    Abs(YourTable.[ID] - T.ID) <= 1
```

Comment: Thank you, that works excellent for above 'table'. Could you maybe suggest how to edit it, if I have more than one 'D' type record?

Comment: See extended answer, please.

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered if you feel so.